# Cant access Remote MySQL from my localhost xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, remote-server

I am trying to connect to a Remote MySQL from Hostgator but it gives me an error which says `Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.` I have already added my IP to Access Host in Hostgator and still, no luck is there any configuration that I am supposed to do, I am currently using xampp v3.2.4 on windows 10 machine.

here is the configuration code:

```
      class Database {
      private $host = myip;
    private $user = DB_USERNAME_FROM_Hostgator;
    private $pass = DB_PASS_FROM_Hostgator;
      private $dbname = DB_NAME_FROM_Hostgator;
    
       private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;
    
    public function __construct() {
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        $options = array (
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION 
        );

        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO ($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }       // Catch any errors
        catch ( PDOException $e ) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    
    // Prepare statement with query
    public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }
    
    // Bind values
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
        if (is_null ($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int ($value) :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool ($value) :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null ($value) :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default :
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }
    
    // Execute the prepared statement
    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }
    
    // Get result set as array of objects
    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    
    // Get single record as object
    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    
    // Get record row count
    public function rowCount(){
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }
    
    // Returns the last inserted ID
    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do have MySQL account privileges to worldwide access to? (`*`) most probably by default it's created with `localhost` privileges. Check it.

Comment: @biesior i have set to ALL PRIVILEGES

Comment: Login to DB i.e. via PhpMyAdmin on remote server and check in user lists if your account reflected it? Maybe flushing the privileges is required> just trying to guess.

Comment: They do say this on their site, have you tried contactng them? `Many of our servers block port 3306 inbound. If you are getting a Connection Refused error when trying to connect, please contact us via phone or Live Chat requesting that we open port 3306 for your IP to connect to MySQL remotely.`

Comment: @cOle2 thank you let me see what they say

Comment: I was able to fix it, turns out there is a special IP address they give if you want to access it remotely